# Problem with Rest-API for WooComerce Product Add-ons

Tags: javascript, react-native, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

In my react native project I am creating an app based on an ecommerce.

Product add-ons are installed on the woocommerce site to ask the user to enter some parameters.

The problem is that I can't download via API the required parameters, added with Product add-ons for each individual product, there is no trace in the downloaded json.

How can I solve it?

This is my product catalog json download code:

```
async getProducts(page = 1, products = []) {
try {
  const response = await this.api.get('/wp-json/wc/v3/products', {
    params: {
      per_page: 100,
      page
    }
  });
  products = products.concat(response.data);

  // Log the structure of a single product object
  if (response.data.length > 0) {
    console.log('Struttura di un singolo prodotto:', JSON.stringify(response.data[0], null, 2));
  }

  // Verifica se ci sono altre pagine da recuperare
  if (response.headers['x-wp-totalpages'] && page < parseInt(response.headers['x-wp-totalpages'])) {
    console.log("Pagina: " + page);
    return this.getProducts(page + 1, products);
  } else {
    console.log('Prodotti totali recuperati:', products.length);
    return products;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Errore durante il download dei prodotti:', error);
}
```

}